# How to get the pos of an element in a Heap-Array with a specific prio in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-tree

is it actually possible to get the position of an object in a Heap-Array with a specific priority in constant time?

For instance you have a max-heap H = [15, 14, 13, 10, 5, 2, 3, 0] and you should give the position of the object with the priority 10 out of the array H which is 4.

I have no idea how to solve this problem without searching the array, however searching algorithms can't be performed in constant time.

Any idea or tip?

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the only way to do it is remove items while counting, then add them all back in.  Or there are other options with the same asymptotic runtime.

The heap property only guarantees that the min (or max) element is the root. It says nothing about how other items are ordered.

If you change your question to binary search tree, the answer is different (though still not constant time).

Also, if you change the question from "priority" to "tree position," the answer is different.

Comment: Hello Gene,

thank you indeed for the prompt answer.

So then, either I misunderstand the exercise or there is a mistake in it.

The exercise says:

_"Describe on how to get the position for a given priority p in a heap array in constant time.
If p does not exist in the array, then return 0.

Notice: Modify the functions repair_up() and repair_down() in such a manner, so there asymptotic runtime remains unchanged.
Assume that all operations are performed on an initially empty heap."_

I will ask my teacher about it and give you feedback.

Greetings

Comment: @John Yes.  I think your teacher may be thinking about a complete binary search tree stored in an array rather than a heap.  In this case, the priority can be calculated quickly.

Comment: @John Or your teacher could be thinking of _level_ (i.e. distance from the root) rather than priority.  This would make sense with respect to the hint on how to do the problem.